Wrapping figures next to display math equations
I am trying to wrap a figure around displayed math text.
My code:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,fancyhdr,wrapfig,lipsum}
\begin{document}

\section{Some filler text}
\lipsum[1]
\section{The important part}
The equations below are the important part
a) Bla bla bla
\[2(40+30)\times4+40\times30=1760\left(\text{m}^2\right)\]
b) Bla bla bla
\[30\ \text{cm}=0.3\ \text{m}\]
\[40\times30(4-0.3)=440\left(\text{m}^3\right)\]
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{figure.png}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

I want the figure to be positioned to the right of the equations.
The figure: 

You could use two minipages next to each other, one for your equations and one for the figure. Much easier than wrapping stuff around an image.

Did you test the code as it is shown in your question?

You might also want to have a look at the siunitx package to get proper spacing between your numbers and units.

I would suggest to not wrap the text around the image and instead use minipages to place your equations and figure side-by-side:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,fancyhdr,wrapfig,lipsum}
\usepackage{caption,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\section{Some filler text}
\lipsum[1]
\section{The important part}
The equations below are the important part

\noindent\begin{minipage}{.55\textwidth}
a) Bla bla bla
\[2(40+30)\times4+40\times30=1760\left(\unit{m^2}\right)\]
b) Bla bla bla
\[\qty{30}{cm}=\qty{0.3}{m}\]
\[40\times30(4-0.3)=440\left(\unit{m^3}\right)\]
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}%
\captionof{figure}{some caption}%
\end{minipage}%

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}



This shows a paracol solution.  The advantage is that paracol supports figures.  The disadvantage is that alignment of the column content can be tricky.  Note that the figure adds \intextsep gaps above and below (just like wrapfig).
MWE stolen from samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,fancyhdr,lipsum}
\usepackage{caption,siunitx}
\usepackage{paracol}
\globalcounter*

\begin{document}

\section{Some filler text}
\lipsum[1]
\section{The important part}
The equations below are the important part

\setcolumnwidth{.55\textwidth}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\vfil% center text in column
\noindent
a) Bla bla bla
\[2(40+30)\times4+40\times30=1760\left(\unit{m^2}\right)\]
b) Bla bla bla
\[\qty{30}{cm}=\qty{0.3}{m}\]
\[40\times30(4-0.3)=440\left(\unit{m^3}\right)\]
\switchcolumn
\begin{figure}[ht]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}%
\caption{some caption}
\end{figure}
\end{paracol}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}

